# Saving the Tensorflow cifar10 graph to a protobuf file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been going through the [Tensorflow CNN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/), which uses the cifar10 dataset. Now, I've been trying to modify the given cifar10 code (which is a little out of date) to output a protobuf file that I'll be able to use in a small c++ image recognition program - similar to the format of the [Image Recognition](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition/) tutorial. The overall aim is that I'll be able to create and save a graph from my own dataset.

However, I've had no success. Most of my attempts have been based around the tensorflow freeze_graph.py, which is the only way I've been able to find that is meant to save the graph. However, I've had no success implementing this and have been met with a myriad of errors, such as:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: Unable to open table file 
  /tmp/cifar10_train/checkpoint: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps 
  your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore 
  operator?
```

(when calling freeze_graph.py with the cifar10_train.py generated graph.pbtxt as the input graph, which I am not sure is even valid as an input)

and also:

```
File "....../freeze_graph.py", line 112, in freeze_graph
    saver_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 112, in read
    return pywrap_tensorflow.ReadFromStream(self._read_buf, length, status)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: dataset/train
```

(when attempting to save my own checkpoints and input graph to act as inputs for freeze_graph.py).

Any idea what I could possible be doing wrong?

Am I even on the right track, or is there a simpler way to do this?

UPDATE:

I've had some success with the following in writing the protobuf file (read: it doesn't crash/give errors):

```
output_node_names = 'ExponentialMovingAverage'
output_graph = './out_graph.pb'
graph = sess.graph
input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()
output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
  sess,
  input_graph_def, 
  output_node_names.split(",")
)
with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
      f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
print("%d ops in the final graph." % len(output_graph_def.node))
```

However the pb file produced doesn't produce any tensors when used in my recognition code. Should this be producing a valid protobuf file?

Comment: I think savedmodel loader is ready for c++ , that's the new way

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Ok, I'll look into that as an alternative. I'd like to get this working anyway - If only for my own peace of mind.

Comment: Could you show how you generated the input files to freeze_graph.py? What arguments did you pass? For the last UPDATE: it looks like you are serializing the graph to a proto correctly, but how are you trying to consume the graphdef proto? More details, please!

Comment: @PeterHawkins If you look at the Tensorflow CNN tutorial (that uses cifar10), that is basically the code I'm using at the moment. The checkpoints etc. are generated by a monitored training session in this code. I'm loading the graph in the same manner as in the Tensorflow Image Recognition tutorial (which uses Inception-v3). I'm thinking that maybe the input/output layers aren't defined properly in the proto, but I'm not entirely sure what they should be or how to ensure they are.